# adding various layers to ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

In cleaning up my code I am starting to use variables to add common elements to my plots (e.g. color scales, titles, ...). I noticed that in general I can add individual layers either explicitly or as variable to a basic plot using `+`.

I also can combine a whole bunch of elements in a single variable using `+` and then add those all together to the basic plot with `+`.

However, there seem to be combinations of layers that are somehow 'incompatible'. For example combining `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_color_viridis_d` into a single variable throws an error `Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?` even though both layers were combined without a problem in a variable that also carried `ggtitle` and `scale_linetype_manual`.

What makes these various labels incompatible? And which layers add as glue--so to speak-- that now allows those incompatible layers to be combined?

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- mtcars
data$model <- row.names(data)
data$carb <- as.factor(data$carb)
data$cyl <- as.factor(data$cyl)

#// basic plot
plot <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = carb)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = mpg,  y = hp, linetype = cyl), se = FALSE)

#// add layers explicitly
plot + ggtitle("Title")
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
plot + scale_linetype_manual(name = "Cylinder", values = c("4" = "dashed", "6" = "solid", "8" = "dotted")) 
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
plot + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 5, to = 50, by = 2.5))
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
plot + scale_color_viridis_d(begin = 1, end = 0, alpha = 1, direction = 1, na.value = "gray")
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
#// add individual layers as variables
title          <- ggtitle("Title")
scale_linetype <- scale_linetype_manual(name = "Cylinder", values = c("4" = "dashed", "6" = "solid", "8" = "dotted")) 
scale_x        <- scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 5, to = 50, by = 2.5))
scale_col      <- scale_color_viridis_d(begin = 1, end = 0, alpha = 1, direction = 1, na.value = "gray")
plot + title + scale_linetype + scale_x + scale_col
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
#// combine layers to add and then add to plot
combo <- title + scale_col + scale_linetype + scale_x
plot + combo
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
#// combining these two layers doesn't work
combo <- scale_col + scale_x
#> Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Just the code for easier copy/paste.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- mtcars
data$model <- row.names(data)
data$carb <- as.factor(data$carb)
data$cyl <- as.factor(data$cyl)

#// basic plot
plot <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = carb)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = mpg,  y = hp, linetype = cyl), se = FALSE)

#// add layers explicitly
plot + ggtitle("Title")
plot + scale_linetype_manual(name = "Cylinder", values = c("4" = "dashed", "6" = "solid", "8" = "dotted")) 
plot + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 5, to = 50, by = 2.5))
plot + scale_color_viridis_d(begin = 1, end = 0, alpha = 1, direction = 1, na.value = "gray")

#// add individual layers as variables
title          <- ggtitle("Title")
scale_linetype <- scale_linetype_manual(name = "Cylinder", values = c("4" = "dashed", "6" = "solid", "8" = "dotted")) 
scale_x        <- scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 5, to = 50, by = 2.5))
scale_col      <- scale_color_viridis_d(begin = 1, end = 0, alpha = 1, direction = 1, na.value = "gray")
plot + title + scale_linetype + scale_x + scale_col

#// combine layers to add and then add to plot
combo <- title + scale_col + scale_linetype + scale_x
plot + combo

#// combining these two layers doesn't work
combo <- scale_col + scale_x
```

Comment: Actually `combo <- title + scale_col + scale_linetype + scale_x` doesn't work either. It's just NULL. The difference in this case is that `title` is of class `labels`. Adding a `ggproto` object to `title` returns `NULL` which is then added to the next `ggproto` object ... , i.e. here you don't add `ggproto` objects. But you end up with `NULL`. If you change the order, e.g. put the title at the end then you run in the same issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. I didn't even look at the plots properly to see if it was rendering what it was supposed to render! I just assumed it worked since it didn't spit out an error. It seems like the safest thing to do is to just add each individual object as a separate variable -- unless I can understand/look up which one of the objects is a ggproto object and which one is not.

Comment: Instead of putting the layers in separate vars you could simply put them in a list. You can always add a list of layers to a ggplot. To this end I recommend to have a look at ch. 19 of the ggplot2 book. See https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html#multiple-components.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this solution out. That makes perfect sense to simply go via a list. I actually have a hardcopy of the book next to my desk... but I have gotten through it all. :( So much to learn.